# Raspberry PI4 - OpenVino - Open CV DNN - net.forward - Segmentation fault - NCS2 - Myriad

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, intel, openvino

I am using OpenVino recent kit : l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.2.120.tgz
Raspberry  - Pi4.
Open CV 4.3.0-openvino.

Trying to use the OpenCV DNN with tensorflow net and also caffe. But getting segmentation fault at net.forward() call.

Below is the code for tensorflow in Python . I do not know how to proceed and resolve it. I tried searching and could not find a working solution for this.

Steps I am doing ( the paths are configured correctly )

## Initialize the tensorflow net

tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(PATH_TO_CKPT, PATH_TO_LABELS)

tensorflowNet.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_MYRIAD) ## set to use the NCS2

## PASS THE BLOB TO TENSORFLOW NETWORK

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False)

## pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and

tensorflowNet.setInput(blob)

print ("Before forward")

**detections =tensorflowNet.forward()**

print("after forward")

It fails at .forward method.Console out put is as below.

pi@raspberrypi:~/guardeyelite $ python3 OpenCVTensorFlow.py
Frame found

processing frame done

Before forward

Segmentation fault

Comment: Any chance to share the model and the source code you are using? It would help reproduce your error. Have you tried to run your app on a PC? Using another backend?

Comment: The code, more or less is as above. Nothing complex. I have ssd inception v2 files. The frozen inference graph and pbtxt file (generated by using text to graph utility by TF). I did not try on any machine. Is it possible to share the code with you via some other channel?

Comment: When using GDB Python3 - I get the following : [New Thread 0xa0a29460 (LWP 3574)]

Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xaefeeeda in ?? ()
   from /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/ngraph/lib/libngraph.so
(gdb)

Comment: I have a guess that this model is too complex and cannot be parsed properly by OpenCV reader. I would suggest to convert the model by model optimizer using the following command: `python3 ./mo.py --input_model ~/Downloads/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ~/Downloads/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config --transformations_config ./extensions/front/tf/ssd_support.json` and then tried to read the model by `readNetFromModelOptimizer`.

Comment: More info about converting detection models from TensorFlow to OpenVINO format: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_tf_specific_Convert_Object_Detection_API_Models.html If your model somehow differs from the ordinary ssd inception v2 I can give it a try in my local setup. You can find my contacts in my Github profile.

Comment: Thanks, I will contact you there. My model is usual one. I tried also with Yolo model and doesnt work.

Comment: Managed to resolve it. By compiling everything from source. Also cross compiled opencv contrib ( this is optional, but i need it). The openvino tool kit version from Jan,2020 helped me at the time of writing. Once we install openCV(4.2 openvino) from source. The setvars.sh have to be modified to redirect the python path and libpath to opencv folder.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you were able to resolve your issue by [building from source](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057005/boards-and-kits.html). There have been a couple of OpenVINO Releases since this discussion. Please let us know if you continue to see this issue on the latest [OpenVINO for Raspbian OS](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html) Release.